# Second principle of mathematical induction for identity permutation

Tags: group-theory, induction

I am going through Gallian's book on group theory, and while proving that identity permutation is an Even permutation, author assumes the identity permutation is of $r$ $2$-cycles and in one case, if the $r$ $2$-cycles reduces to $r-2$, then using second principle of mathematical induction,  $ r-2$ is even. How is that leap made using second principle of mathematical induction? I understand the assumptions made in first principle induction, but how does it work in second principle?

Answer (score 1):

Strong mathematical induction allows you to prove a statement $P(n)$ by assuming that $P(k)$ applies to *every* $k<n$. In this case, he is proving the statement for $n$ $2$-cycles, and when that reduces to $n-2$, it can be assumed to be true because $n-2=k<n$.

Comment: Ok. But what will the statement be, when k is odd? This is what I am struggling with. And what if my n is odd? n-2 will then be odd, right? please bear with me.